# Sqlite query - How I can select a predecessor?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table below:

```
ID    name    Last
0     Joe     Doe
1     Hut     Nob
2     Lis     Hug
3     Edy     mur
```

I use this query to select an ID:

```
SELECT name FROM myDatabase WHERE ID = 2
```

In this case the query returns me the string **Lis**, now, How I can select the predecessor value?

Simple, the predecessor from 2 is 1, so I need only to do `WHERE ID < 2` or `WHERE ID = 2 - 1`.

But this method have a problem! Lets suppose that I delete that row (ID = 1), the query will return **null**, because that ID not exists.

So, in this example, how I can select the predecessor from ID 2 and return ID 0?  (ID 1 is gone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery to find max `ID` that is lower than `ID` that you provided:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable m
WHERE m.id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id)
              FROM mytable m2
              WHERE m2.ID < 2);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/57e55/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Get all the smaller IDs, and from those, take only the largest one:

```
SELECT name
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID < 2
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```